# Бесконечная компиляция после приминения multidex

Tags: java, android, gradle, multidex

Была задача пропарсить `.xlsx` файл.

Попытался применить библиотеки для парсинга файлов, в результате получил ошибку, что в библиотеках слишком много методов (вроде, больше 65К).

После недолгого поиска в гугле наткнулся на вариант с применением `multidex`, однако перестал компилироваться проект (уже 40 минут...).

Вот мой `gradle.build` файл:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') //Библиотеки для парсинга тут
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

---

Подскажите, из-за чего это происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вы можете значительно ускорить сборку проекта подняв `minSDKVersion` до `21`** (а собирая релизную сборку, Вы можете понизить `API Level`, если он не завязан на используемые средства, но процесс сборки будет таким же долгим).

**Более подробно:**

(При `minSDKVersion` менее `21` – при использовании `Dalvik`) сборка проекта занимает продолжительное время, так как:

> A multidex configuration requires significantly increased build processing time because the build system must make complex decisions about what classes must be included in the primary DEX file and what classes can be included in secondary DEX files. This means that routine builds performed as part of the development process with multidex typically take longer and can potentially slow your development process.

Вкратце: во время сборки приложения с `multiDexEnabled true` происходит долгий процесс выбора: какие классы должны включаться в основной `DEX`-файл, а какие во вторичные.

Как исправить:

> In order to mitigate the typically longer build times for multidex output, you should create two variations on your build output using the Android plugin for Gradle productFlavors: a development flavor and a production flavor.
>
> For the development flavor, set a minimum SDK version of 21. This setting generates multidex output much faster using the ART-supported format. For the release flavor, set a minimum SDK version which matches your actual minimum support level. This setting generates a multidex APK that is compatible with more devices, but takes longer to build.

Вкратце: **решение основывается на поднятии версии `minSDKVersion`** до `21`, при которой проект будет собираться быстрее (так как в `API Level 21` `Dalvik` был заменен на `ART`, который нативно поддерживает `multiple dex files`).

Но если Вам необходимо поддерживать устройства с меньшей `minSDKVersion`, то Вы можете использовать **product flavors** для настройки различных конфигураций:

```
productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
```

При разработке Вы можете собирать `dev`-конфигурацию (в которой будет `minSdkVersion 21`), а для релиза – `prod`-конфигурацию (в которой `minSdkVersion` будет ниже). Но в релизной конфигурации приложение будет собираться, разумеется, дольше.

Подробнее можно почитать по ссылке: [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Только чего-то с `multipledex'ом` выдало 100+ ошибок (спустя час :)). Сейчас выставлю версию до 21-го API, а потом буду разбираться.

Comment: Кстати, включение минимум 21-го API не работает, все равно ошибка про 64к метода.

Comment: @bukashka101, то есть при `multiDexEnabled true` и `minSdkVersion 21` получаете ошибку более 64K методов?

Comment: А что, еще и  и `multedex` вручную включать? В документации же написано, что она по умолчанию стоит для API 21+...

Comment: Все, включил и заработало. Правда выдало 144 ошибки, но все заработало :)).

Comment: @bukashka101, А, вообще да. А Вы используете `product flavors` или подняли версию в единственной конфигурации? Если первое, то Вы точно собираете `dev`?

Comment: Поднял версию конфигурации.

Comment: @bukashka101, Тогда странно, ведь `ART natively supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files.` Попробуйте еще отключить `Instant Run`.

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: @bukashka101, Многие непонятные ситуации возникают из-за включенной функции `Instant Run`.